# D3.js Accessing local file in IE9 and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, d3.js, local

While working with D3, the following code can access the contents of the .csv file in firefox but not in IE9.

```
        d3.csv("cust_data.csv", function (csv) {})
```

cust_data.csv is in the same folder as the .html
Can anyone suggest the reason for this. What can be done to access it in IE9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be useful to know what error you are getting. In the case it is given you some sort of permission/IO access error, I would assume the error is because you are not running it using a local web server. A description of how to run the python web server can be found [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki)

Comment: thanks for the clue. At the D3JS official site, they say for using IE9 with D3 a local web server should be used. It is working fine while running with localhost. Sorry,my bad. I should have checked the instructions on http://d3js.org first.